finding the Kernel of a LT with trace
I have encountered a problem that I was able to solve partially. 
Given a matrix P which is invertible above a field F, we define $T:M_{n}(F)\rightarrow F$ by the following $T(A)=tr(PA)$.
Prove that T is linear and find its kernel. 
So I managed to prove that it is linear because for every $A_{1}, A_{2}\in M_{n}$ it follows that $T(A_{1}+A_{2})=T(A_{1})+T(A_{2})$. But I do not know how to find the Ker. Also I did not use the fact that P is invertible in anywhere so why would they tell it?

presumably you can find a way to apply rank-nullity to this problem...
